# Spring boot gradle dependencies managment

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have the following gradle settings:

```
plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.0'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
id 'java'
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit-test'
}
```

How can I lock or specify exactly the versions of all the dependencies libs, how do I check the compatibility with the other libs and chose the most new and updated ones?

as I understand - spring boot doesn't need spring framework specified?

1. checked other Stackoverflow posts.
2. checked compatibility matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dependencyManagement {
imports {
    mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.0.0"
}
}
```

solved the issue.